# Issue upgrading React Native to latest version 0.71

Tags: react-native

I tried using the command "npx react-native upgrade" to update my React Native app from version 0.67 to version 0.71, however, this command has never worked for me. Therefore, I had to manually apply changes using [upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/), but here I encountered the following strange alphanumeric numbers when manually applying all the modifications to "ios/appName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj":

[image]

How can I handle this problem in my current project? Is it acceptable to duplicate them in my project as it seems that these alphanumeric references vary from one project to the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I upgraded React Native, I had a similar problem, but it turned out that I didn't need to make any manual changes to that file line by line; instead, I just made changes to other files, and after running "npx pod-install ios," that file immediately updated.

Update: I realized the file `AppDelegate.m` isn't updated to `AppDelegate.mm`. Therefore, you have to do it manually.

Comment: Did you just change the suffix to `.mm` or did you also change the file content?